# Dealing with data in Single page App (Hybrid mobile app & PHP server)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a hybrid app using intel xdk with PHP server. My app already had a login page(index.html). When the user logged in it will redirect to user.html page.

In user.html, It consists of different `div's` for user's data.
Example:

```
<div class="navigation">the navigation</div>

<div id="home"> -some data content here- </div>
<div id="user-account" style="display:none"> -some data content here- </div>
<div id="messages" style="display:none"> -some data content here- </div>
<div id="transactions" style="display:none"> -some data content here- </div>
<div id="products" style="display:none"> -some data content here- </div>
<div id="videos" style="display:none"> -some data content here- </div>
```

So when I logged in to the app the **home** will be the main page. And the data should be loaded in home page, user-account, messages, transactions etc..

I am thinking that I should run ajax request upon logging in of a user. Requesting to the server to get all the data of this logged in user. 
This could be:

```
SELECT
    `user`.*
    , `user-transactions`.*
    , `user_products`.*
FROM
    `db`.`user`
    INNER JOIN `db`.`user_transactions` 
        ON (`user`.`user_id` = `user_transactions`.`transaction_user_id`)
    INNER JOIN `db`.`user_products` 
        ON (`user`.`user_id` = `user_products`.`uproducts_user_id`);)
```

Then the server respond the json data to the App. So now I have all the user's data I needed to display in the App.

So when the user go to other div page the data was already loaded. I am also thinking to save this data to localStorage so that when the remember me option was selected upon logging in, the user can still view the data in offline mode. And it can be updated(send ajax request again) by refreshing the page.

Am I going to the right direction? What are different approaches in dealing with data in a Hybrid app (in terms of displaying)?

Comment: Somehow yes, but I would prefer using Angular or React for managing my application. They've done sucha these things for you

Comment: @AliTorabi Did't try it yet. How do I learn from it? reference for a newbie?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of frameworks to create hybrid mobile app. It's better to use one ;)
See : http://noeticforce.com/best-hybrid-mobile-app-ui-frameworks-html5-js-css

Maybe, if you can use a plugin to store your datas in SQLite database it will be better (and faster if you have a lot of datas) than localStorage.

Hope to be helpful !